# How do I count the number of features matched?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I used this FLANN feature matching. I also tried it with both ORB and BRISK descriptor. It showed the results. Now how do I count the number of features matched? I tried `print(len(matches)` but it gave me 1589. I dont think its 1589 looking at the picture.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img1 = cv.imread('trainImage1.png', 0)
img2 = cv.imread('trainImage2.png', 0)

brisk = cv.BRISK_create(60, 2, 2)

kp1, des1 = brisk.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = brisk.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_LSH, table_number=6, key_size=12, multi_probe_level=1)
search_params = dict(checks=50)

flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

matchesMask = [[0, 0] for i in range(len(matches))]

for i, (m, n) in enumerate(matches):
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        matchesMask[i] = [1, 0]

draw_params = dict(matchColor=(0, 255, 0), singlePointColor=(255, 0, 0), matchesMask=matchesMask, flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_DEFAULT)

img3 = cv.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, matches, None, **draw_params)

print(len(matches))

plt.imshow(img3,), plt.show()
```

[Feature Matching Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV6Pb.jpg)

Will anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to draw matches points, you need to give empty array as matchesMask.

```
draw_params = dict(matchColor=(0, 255, 0), singlePointColor=(255, 0, 0), matchesMask=[], flags=cv.DrawMatchesFlags_DEFAULT)
```

Comment: I did as you said. But there are a lot of matches now and I think most of them are false matches. I also can't seem to count the number of features matched. It still shows 1589 for all every two image in my dataset (I have 6 planar mages taken from different viewpoints).

Answer (score 0):

These algorithms has error. That's why you have to filter the results. One general filter is size filter. That means you omit the matches that are smaller or greater than a size. These maximum and minimum depend on your case. size ration and place of the matches are another filters.

Answer (score 0):

I think the number of matches is truly 1589. The result in your picture, only draw several matches.

Try to compare your first train image to random image that actually don't relate each other. If the number decrease, then the matches is really showing the number of matches object.